# Skip non-array attributes at a specific nesting level in JSON

Tags: json, bash, sh, jq

I am trying to retrieve Firefox's blacklisted hosts from [the source list it uses](https://github.com/disconnectme/disconnect-tracking-protection/blob/master/services.json) so that I can use it for another browser (Qutebrowser).

I have been reasonably successful with `jq` to parse the JSON.

```
#!/bin/sh
for term in Advertising Content Social Analytics Fingerprinting Cryptomining Disconnect; do
    jq ".categories.$term[][][][]" services.json
done
```

However, a few deepest objects (which are always in the same nesting level) of some categories contain extra information that breaks the `jq`, such as `"performance": "true"` below:

```
{
  "categories": {
    ...
    "Cryptomining": [
      {
        "a.js": {
          "http://zymerget.bid": [
            "alflying.date",
            "alflying.win",
            ...
            "zymerget.faith"
          ],
          "performance": "true"
        }
      },
      {
        "CashBeet": {
          "http://cashbeet.com": [
            "cashbeet.com",
            "serv1swork.com"
          ]
        }
      },
      ...
```

So that, for example, when the loop comes to `jq ".categories.Cryptomining[][][][]" services.json`, it raises an error and stops processing the category:

```
"alflying.date"
"alflying.win"
...
"zymerget.faith"
jq: error (at servicesN.json:11167): Cannot iterate over string ("true")
```

Is there any way to disregard those non-array attributes with `jq`? As an *extra*, please let me know if I could ditch the for loop and do the whole process in a single `jq` (because currently, as can be seen above, I list all the categories in the for loop).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to disregard those non-array attributes with `jq`?

Yes, [`arrays` built-in](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#arrays,objects,iterables,booleans,numbers,normals,finites,strings,nulls,values,scalars).

> As an *extra*, please let me know if I could ditch the for loop and do the whole process in a single `jq` (because currently, as can be seen above, I list all the categories in the for loop).

[Array/Object Value Iterator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Array/ObjectValueIterator:.%5B%5D) does that for you.

```
jq '.categories[][][][] | arrays[]' services.json
```

But, for this particular task, it seems like you don't even need `arrays` at all; the following command yields the same output:

```
jq '.categories[][][][][]?' services.json
```

See [`.[]?`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#.%5B%5D?).

Answer (score 0):

Given

```json
{
  "categories": {
    "Cryptomining": [
      {
        "a.js": {
          "http://zymerget.bid": [
            "alflying.date",
            "alflying.win",
            "zymerget.faith"
          ],
          "performance": "true"
        }
      },
      {
        "CashBeet": {
          "http://cashbeet.com": [
            "cashbeet.com",
            "serv1swork.com"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

As an alternative to nested paths you could use a recursive descent:

```
.. | strings
```

Which produces:

```
"alflying.date"
"alflying.win"
"zymerget.faith"
"true"
"cashbeet.com"
"serv1swork.com"
```

To exclude "true" either make it a boolean *or* exclude strings that don't have a `.` in it:

```
.. | strings | select(contains("."))
```

Returns:

```
"alflying.date"
"alflying.win"
"zymerget.faith"
"cashbeet.com"
"serv1swork.com"
```